# Antiderivative of $\int_{1}^{R} \frac{1} {x^s}dx$

Tags: integration

So this is my first question..
I have got the following and I need to calculate the integral. But I already fail trying to make the antiderivative.. I know that $\displaystyle \frac{1} {x^s}$ = $x^{-s}$ but at this point it stops

$$\int_{1}^{R} \frac{1} {x^s}dx$$

I hope you can simply answer my question, thanks.

Comment: Hint: $s=1$ is a special case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $s\neq 1$ then $$\int\frac{1}{x^s}\mathrm dx=-\frac{1}{(s-1)x^{s-1}}$$

If s=1 then $$\int\frac{1}{x}\mathrm dx=ln|x|$$

Comment: In the case of $\neq$ 1 I cannot solve the function if I insert R and 1. I don't know how to go on with this: $\frac {1} {(s-1)*R^{s-1}} - \frac {1} {(s-1}$

Comment: No the result is $\frac{1}{s-1}\left( 1-\frac{1}{R^{s-1}}\right)$ because we have a "-". That's the result of computing the integral. If it's not enaugh it means you have another question right?

Comment: So if I got to this point, can I just stop and say for my boarders 0 and $\pi$ this is the result?

Comment: Of course what's the problem? $R=\pi$ so the result is $\frac{1}{s-1}\left( 1-\frac{1}{\pi^{s-1}}\right)$

Comment: I wasn't sure about The ending.. But now I am. thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that the antiderivative of $x^n$ is $\frac{1}{n+1} x^{n+1}$, when $n\ne -1$. If $n=-1$, the antiderivative is $\ln{|x|}$.

Answer (score 1):

Remember the rule for differentiating polynomials:

$$(x^n)' =n\cdot x^{n-1}$$and hence for $s\neq1$

$$\int x^{-s}dx=\frac{x^{1-s}}{1-s}$$